# How to push fixed postion block in another respevite block height

Tags: html, css

I have left side navigation Bar in that I have one block is navigation another block filters block. The first block I have made Relative and second block I have made Fixed because every screen resolution I want to fix in the bottom but the small screen I have to make the top block with scroll if fixed block will override. I want to show a fixed block with full data.

[image]

HTML

```html
<div class="side-nav">
 <nav>
  <ul>
    <li>link 1</li>
    <li>link 2</li>
    <li>link 3</li>
    <li>link 4</li>
    <li>link 5</li>
    <li>link 6</li>
    <li>link 7</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="fixed-block">
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummied text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
</nav>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.side-nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    min-width: 290px;
    max-width: 290px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #303D74;
}

ul {
  padding: 0px;
}

ul > li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #f4f4f4;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #7889CD;
}

.fixed-block {
  position : absolute;
  bottom : 0;
  color: white;
}
```

We can't give fixed height if I will give height: 300px; overflow: auto; then bigger screen resolution will also have fixed height. I tried with VH also.

Comment: do u want second block is fixed at bottom at all resolutions?

Comment: yes @Manikandan2811